# strip_tags php removes too much

Tags: php, strip-tags

There's a little trouble with a malformed string including html (see the '' at the beginning and the <'blabla) and the function strip_tags() from PHP.

I've this code:

```
$str = "To: ''blablal@johndoe.com' <'blablal@johndoe.com>\nSubject: Hello World\nDear Ladies <b>and</b> Gentlemen,";
echo strip_tags($str);
```

With the following outout:

```
To: ''blablal@johndoe.com'
```

My wanted/expected result is:

```
To: ''blablal@johndoe.com' 
Subject: Hello World
Dear Ladies and Gentlemen,
```

Do you have any idea to get this?

Comment: Why is there a single quote in your email address?

Comment: @Lithilion: I just got this text to filter - I've no influence on the source of the string. I think melvin has the best approach to it. It works with invalid html, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If stip_tags() didn't work as you expect, try this one.

```
$str = "To: ''blablal@johndoe.com' <'blablal@johndoe.com>\nSubject: Hello World\nDear Ladies <b>and</b> Gentlemen,";

$val = preg_replace('/<[^>]+?>/', ' ', $str);
```

Your `$val` contains string without html values

[image]

Comment: I think you want `/<[^>]+?>/`

Comment: In this example it doesn't make a difference. But generally you want to absorb all non-terminating characters (in this case `>`) in between the start and finish of the regex.

Comment: So my regex should be `preg_replace('/<[^>]+?>/', ' ', $str);` ?

Comment: Happy to help. Thanks to @Nick

Answer (score 0):

> Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.

See the [PHP manual](http://php.net/strip_tags):

Your case is the invalid HTML. The [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/) says

```
Bad character ' after <. Probable cause: Unescaped <. Try escaping it as &lt;.
```

Comment: As mentioned above I have no influence on the origin, so it may be possible that I receive invalid html stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when stripper finds a `<` that follows a non-whitespace character it assumes that it is inside a tag. Then inside a tag if it sees a quotation mark it sets a flag (`in_q`) then looks for a closing pair. If it finds a closing pair it unsets `in_q` flag ([`in_q = 0;`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c#L5251)) but if it doesn't find it then it assumes it is still inside quotes and consumes everything up to the end and removes it from the output.

If you have such malformed tags in your input string you'd better use regular expressions instead:

```
preg_replace('~<\S[^<>]*>~', '', $str);
```

See [live demo here](https://3v4l.org/eHrvj)